# dynamic image onload after append?

Tags: jquery

I'm facing the problem that, after i append a bunch of images in a div (one per div) to a container (div), i don't get the onload function..

this is in a loop including a bunch of variables

```
$('#container').append('<div class="tile" style="position:absolute; top:'+(i*size)+'px; left:'+(j*size)+'px; width:'+size+'px; height:'+size+'px; overflow:hidden;" ><img src="'+map[i][j]+'"/></div>');
```

All variables are fine and all images are loaded correctly but this never works

```
$('.tile img').live('load', function(){
console.log("loaded");
});
```

or

```
$('.tile img').on('load', function(event){
console.log("loaded");
});
```

I've tried with the newer .on jQuery function, and no go..

Edit : 
[+]added .on code (both functions are placed on top right after document ready)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:  I played around with it a bit and the following strategy also works for the load event on a newly created image.  First I'm creating the image then appending it into the div before appending that to the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/sHGm9/1/

```
$('.slideshow').each(function(i) {

    var $img = $('<img src="..." />').on('load', function(){
        alert('loaded');
    });

    $(this).append( $('<div class="tile" style="" ></div>').append($img) );               
    // you'd need to just use your div example here

});
```

Original Answer:

I can think of two things.. Add the on/live before you append or change it to something like this:

```
var $img = $('<img src="..." />');

$img.on('load', function() {
    alert('loaded');
});

$('#slideshow').append($img);  // adapted for my example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/sHGm9/

Comment: Ok, live is actually deprecated as you may already know.. The example in my answer does actually work so you may try to create the jquery object first add the on load and then append that object.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I recently had to deal with this exact issue, and found a slightly simpler solution:

```
$(".container").append(yourImageOrImages);
setImages();

function setImages() {
    $(".container img").each(function() {
        $(this).on('load', function(){
            // Your code to run when done loading
        });
    });
}
```